# Excel wrongly read scientific formatted numbers in csv

Tags: excel, csv, number-formatting

I have a csv file with numbers written in scientific notation (ex. `2.8570890426635534e-05` ) but when i open the csv in excel ( both by opening directly and by importing data in the Data tab)  the number that excel display is `2,87509E+11`.

I have even tried to change the encoding format when reading the csv (ISO, WINDOWS, DOS, UTF-8, ...) but none of them seems to work properly.

Anyone knows where the problem might be ?

Comment: You will need to change the `.` to `,` BEFORE importing or opening in Excel.

Comment: What are your windows regional settings for decimal and thousands separators?

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing using Power Query from the Data tab, after selecting to Import:

- Transform
- Right click on the column

  - Change Type / Using Locale
  - Data Type: Decimal Number
  - Locale English (United States)

[image]

In the Applied Steps menu, you will see

- Changed Type
- Changed Type with Locale

Delete that first Changed Type step.

[image]